# Can you check a server before doing a window.location change?

Tags: javascript

Mainly what I need to do is `window.location = http://myserver.com` with a conditional statement that says if you can connect to this server then do it, else stay on the current window.location and prompt a message that says you cant connect.

Answer (score 1):

do a check by by testing if your server (given that it's the same domain you're on, otherwise it will throw an allow-origin-not-null or something) is up:

```
function hasInternets() {
    console.log("hasInternets: " + window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" + Math.random());
    var s = $.ajax({ 
        type: "HEAD",
        url: window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" + Math.random(),
        async: false
    }).status;
        console.log("s: " +s);
    //thx http://www.louisremi.com/2011/04/22/navigator-online-alternative-serverreachable/

    return s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304; }
```